# Add additions to a list by year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the number of new categories that I added to my inventory each year.  I'm currenty using countif(Range, ">0") and then subtracting the results from previous years, but I'm having to offset this because sometimes I  because I have zero of that item in a subsequent year (e.g., Category 2, 2014).  Is there a way I can write a formula to count new categories added by year easily?

```
           2013 2014 2015
Category 1   1   4   0
Category 2   2   0   6
Category 3   0   5   1
```

Comment: Use COUNTIFS():  `=COUNTIFS(B:B,0,C:C,0)`  This will only count it if both 2013 and 2014 are 0.  You can add other columns if you want.

Comment: Since adding zero to a [SUM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) does not change the total, why are you bothering with [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) ?

Comment: Given your provided sample data, what are your expected results?

Comment: I'm not trying to sum.  I'm looking at each year and adding the number of new categories that were added.  As for results, I'm expecting 2 for 2013 (since 2 new categories were added), 1 for 2014 (since only Category 3 is a new category), and 0 for 2015 (since no new categories were added).

Comment: Is there any other info that might be helpful to help you guys find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're looking for is possible with the data provided in the example. From your sample table, I have no way of knowing what year which category has been added; thus no way of counting new categories added by year. For instance, Category 3 could have been there from the start but just not used in 2013. If that were the case, the result you'd want (3 new for 2013, and 0 for 2014 and 2015) would be different than what you described in the comments.
Can you add information about when the Categories were created somewhere else? You could keep count in another sheet or you could add a column left of the Category one to input the year it was created. That's just two examples that would allow you to get the information you seek.